# Using unsigned char instead of char because of its range

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, char, unsigned

I've been working on a small pure C client application (my first :/) which uses TCP socket for communication with the server. The Server sends me a packet (C structure) in which the first byte contains the size of the packet.

The problem is that server is using unsigned char to represent the size of the packet because char is signed (from -128 to +127) and +127 is not enough to represent size that can be up to 255 in some packets. => I need a unsigned char buffer;

In Linux, the second parameter of recv() function is void * which means I can declare a void *buffer and there is no problem. But recv() in Windows (MinGW) has char * instead of void *. Which give me warning "Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible pointer types 'char *' and 'unsigned char *'"

Is it possible to solve this problem? Here is the code. Thanks.

PS: I'm using NON BLOCKING sockets.

```
 int recvsize = 0;
unsigned char tmpsize;
int index = 0;
unsigned char *buffer;

while (1) {

    recvsize = recv(server, &tmpsize, sizeof(unsigned char), 0); // every packet starts with one byte where is its length

    if (recvsize > 0 ) {
         buffer = malloc(tmpsize * sizeof(unsigned char)); //memory allocation according to the size of packet
         buffer[0] = tmpsize--; //get back the size value to the buffer
         recvsize = 0;


        do { //loop over and over until you do not have all bytes of the packet
            recvsize = recv(server, &buffer[++index], tmpsize, 0);

            if (recvsize == 0)
                break;


            tmpsize -=recvsize;
            index += recvsize;

        } while (tmpsize != 0);

    }
sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: `char` might be signed on your platform. The standard leaves this to the implementation, In general, when transfering data between different systems (and most times also in the same system), using `stdint.h` types and proper serialization is the prefered way. Otherwise a tarpit is waiting.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always 1, so `... * sizeof(unsigned char)` is not needed.  Should code want to note the scaling by the size of the variable, suggest `buffer = malloc(tmpsize * sizeof *buffer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the pointer to the correct type. So use:

```
(char *) (&buffer[++index])
```

Also, why are you creating a blocking scheme by repeating a non-blocking operation in a sleep loop? Either use blocking sockets or use non-blocking sockets, but don't create some fake in-between thing. (If, for example, a malicious or slow client sends you only one byte, you'll spin on `recv`.)

Lastly, why are you reading only one byte in the first call to `recv`? You need the rest of the data anyway, so why make the kernel give it to you in tiny drops? Why not read as many bytes as you can and, with luck, avoid the need to call `recv` a second time?

Comment: "why are you reading only one byte in the first call"  Hmmm, perhaps there could be multiple messages and by reading "as many bytes as you can", might not code get multiple or partial messages and then have to manage that?

Comment: @chux Yes, of course. That's the nature of TCP. Right now, he's forcing the kernel to do it. He already handles partial messages.

Comment: Thanks for extremely quick response! I forgot to delete this sleep statement, I just want to test something. Sorry for that. I read only one byte and then rest of the packet because I do not want to parse a large buffer [512] or [1024] where can be a lot of packets or some incomplete ones. I am lazy to code that.

Comment: @Cpt.Rambler Without the sleep, you'll just burn the CPU in a tight loop waiting for data.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know, you are right. Then, what do you thing by "fake in-between thing", this do-while loop?

Comment: @Cpt.Rambler Yes. Exactly. If you just want to block until something happens, use blocking sockets. If you use non-blocking sockets, use them with some sane socket discovery scheme such as poll. (Why are you using non-blocking sockets anyway if you just have to fake a way to block on them?)