# Recv() in Winsock requires signed buffer

Tags: c++, sockets

I use `recv()` on Linux with `unsigned char buffer` and it works well.

But recv() on Windows requires `signed char` and I don't know why.

I thought the packet can be only ASCII character.

Should I use something like this `(char)buffer`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using unsigned char instead of char because of its range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386158/).

Answer (score 1):

`char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are different types but all are 8 bit. In theory, all "buffers" should be `unsigned char*`. In practise, many functions use a plain `char*` including most Win32 APIs. In all such cases it is a plain 8-bit array.

In short, cast it freely.

Cases that actually need a `char` rather than an `unsigned char` should be obvious to detect and handle.

As per @JJ comment, you also have `std::byte` for raw 8-bit stuff without character characteristics, similar to BYTE in Win32.

Comment: You may want to also mention [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).